# Multi back to back query execution on Elasticsearch huge dataset

Tags: pandas, elasticsearch, elk

I have two datasets, dataset_X (50k) stored locally and dataset_Y(5 million) stored on Elasticsearch.
My use case is to find matches for rows(dataset_X), if any, in dataset_Y.
Match condition:

- 3 columns(col_a,col_b,col_c) must match the same 3 columns in dataset_Y
- there is a set of other columns(say col_m,col_n,col_o ... etc), one of them should match.

My current approach, I am iterating through each row in dataset_X and fetching the rows which matches the above mentioned 1st condition. Then suppose we have found say 20 matches, then I am checking the 2nd condtion locally on my code.

This approach is very slow as I am iterating through each row in dataset_X and querying elasticsearch, I am looking for a more optimised solution. I couldn't find anything over net.